# Partial orders assigmnet

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am struggling with an assignment on partial orders.

The questions is:

Show that in any sequence of $(n − 1)(m − 1) + 1$ integers, either there is a
non-decreasing subsequence of length $n$ or a decreasing subsequence of length $m$.

I would be grateful if someone could help out with this one. I am trying to solve this with induction, but I am stuck as the part of the chain length $m$ and $n$ really makes it hard to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists an increasing subsequence of length $n$, then we are done, so suppose not.

We position the $(n-1)(m-1)+1$ elements in $n-1$ pigeonhole as follows: If the longest increasing subsequence having $x$ as its first element has length $i$, then we put $x$ in pigeonhole $i$. Since we have $n-1$ pigeonholes and $(n-1)(m-1)+1$ elements, there will be a pigeonhole with $m$ elements in it.

The elements in this pigeonhole will constitute a decreasing subsequence (because if two such elements were in increasing order, then the longest increasing subsequence starting from the smallest number would be longer than the longest increasing subsequence starting from the largest number).

Edit: In the above, you can replace the word "increasing" with "non-decreasing", if you wish.